# Copy profile configuration in websphere server 6.1

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-6.1

I have a was6.1 server profile "AppSrv01" in which database and queue configuration is done and some applications are deployed.

I want to create one more profile in my system having the same configurations as AppSrv01 instead of doing it manually again.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Sasank.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to create administration scripts in order to configure your environment.

[Samples for WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/)